# Enabling MVCBuildViews based on Conditional Compilation Symbols

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, msbuild

Is it possible to add conditional steps to your build to check for a custom Conditional Compilation Symbol and enable MVCBuildViews. I've found a way to do this based on the build configuration like so

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
</PropertyGroup>
```

but not sure how to access the compilation symbols instead.

The plan was to add a Symbol under Project Settings > Build > Conditional compilation symbols that controls MVCBuildViews

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using C# you need to configure the compiler to use the Eg`.TEST` symbol when building the views and for this you need to override its configuration in `Web.config` using the following:

```
<system.codedom>
      <compilers>
        <compiler
          language="c#;cs;csharp"
          extension=".cs"
          type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
          compilerOptions="/define:TEST" //Here you need to define your symbol
          warningLevel="1" />
      </compilers>
    </system.codedom>
```

If you apply this directly in the Web.config it will work but will define eg. `TEST` every time. So what you should really do is use `Web.config transformations` so that the symbol is only applied for the correct build configurations.

You can update projects that were created with previous releases of MVC to include build-time validation of views by performing the following steps:

1)Open the project file in a text editor.

2)Add the following element under the top-most  element: `<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>`

3)At the end of the project file, uncomment the `<Target Name="AfterBuild">` element and modify it to match the following:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(MvcBuildViews)'=='true'">
    <AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(ProjectDir)\..\$(ProjectName)" />
</Target>
```

Comment: defining your symbols this way, this this the same as if you added them via Project Properties > Build > Conditional compilation symbols?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach

```
<MvcBuildViews Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'">true</MvcBuildViews>
<MvcBuildViews Condition="'$(Configuration)'!='Release'">false</MvcBuildViews>
```